# Error in function sort

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to use the sort function from STL, but it gives me an error during execution.

My compare function returns true if v is smaller then e:

```
bool smallerThan(VertexEntry &v, VertexEntry &e) {
   if(v.v[0] < e.v[0]) return true;
   else if(v.v[1] < e.v[1]) return true;
   else if(v.v[2] < e.v[2]) return true;
   return false;
}
```

and here is the call:

```
sort(vertices.begin(),vertices.end(),smallerThan);
```

The size of the vector is aprox 400 elements.

Can somebody help me solve my problem?
Thank you!!

Comment: Perhaps if you posted the error, we could help.

Comment: what kind of error do you get?

Comment: By the way, I tried debugging and found out that the error is not in the function smallerThan

Comment: Oh, sorry, my mistake. Invalid operator<

Comment: What happens if `v.v[0] == e.v[0]`?

Comment: I'm surprised it compiles at all! Shouldn't it be `bool smallerThan(const VertexEntry &v, const VertexEntry &e)` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your comparison function is incorrect - it doesn't enforce strict weak ordering.

Use this:

```
bool smallerThan(VertexEntry const & v, VertexEntry const & e) {
   if (v.v[0] < e.v[0]) 
     return true;
   else if(v.v[0] > e.v[0]) 
     return false;
   else if(v.v[1] < e.v[1]) 
     return true;
   else if(v.v[1] > e.v[1])
     return false;
   else if(v.v[2] < e.v[2])
     return true;
   return false;
}
```

Comment: It's better to avoid the `>` operator as it is often not overloaded when `<` is.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I'd say it's better to implement the operators you need, perhaps in terms of `operator<`. For a template sure, for a specific class, I prefer the above.

Comment: @ybungalobill, @Erik: It's user-friendly to implement all the operators every time, but it's an impractical amount of work. If you actually do that, more power to you. In this case, `operator>` is not *needed*.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: No it's not *needed*, and neither is `operator<` since you could implement the function in terms of `operator>` only. IMO, you stick to `operator<`, or even better `std::less`, when you write templated code. For specific classes, implement the operators you need and keep the semantics as they would be for builtin types.

Comment: @Erik: The Standard defines `LessThanComparable` as a common requirement for templates (17.6.3.1), and that is how ordering relationships are defined. Overloading `std::less` for a class or defining `operator>` gets you nowhere with respect to the standard library, or any well-written third-party library.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: That's IMO still not an argument to avoid `operator>` when you have *one specific function* dealing with *one specific class*

Comment: @Erik: Today there's one function or class, tomorrow there might be a dozen. It's called maintainability. Simply put, eliminating a function by rearranging the arguments is a design win.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: To each his own - I'll keep on implementing the operators I need in order to use semantics similar to built-in types. I find that the readability this leads to improves maintainability.

Answer (score 2):

Your comparison operator doesn't enforce strict weak ordering. If you're able to use boost one trick I've seen is to bind your object to a `boost::tuple` and use its strict weak `operator<`.

If you need to write it yourself, something like this should work:

```
bool smallerThan(const VertexEntry &v, const VertexEntry &e)
{
   if(v.v[0] != e.v[0]) return v.v[0] < e.v[0];
   else if(v.v[1] != e.v[1]) return v.v[1] != e.v[1];
   else return v.v[2] < e.v[2];
}
```